# É possível chamar uma modal sem um click?

Tags: bootstrap-3

Bom dia pessoal, é o meu primeiro post, então me desculpem se algo estiver errado. gostaria de saber se é possível chamar uma modal sem clicar em algum botão, por exemplo gostaria de substituir o alert('Mensagem'); do php por uma modal. Dar uma mensagem de inserido com sucesso, gravado com sucesso ou erro !!

Por ex. esta modal:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim é..  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myModal").modal();
 });
</script>

Comment: Neste caso você apenas faça uma condição de if, ai chama

Answer (score 3):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
<?php if($acao=="sucesso"){ ?>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#myModal").modal();
        });
    </script>
<? } ?>

<div id="myModal">teste</div>
```

Neste caso, se houver alguma ação de sucesso, conforme a sua condição, vai chamar a modal automaticamente. Se entendi bem, é isso!

Answer (score 0):

Para não complicar muito, eu faria da seguinte forma: Simule um evento de click no botão que abre o modal para disparar a abertura do modal.

Talvez tenha um jeito melhor de fazer no bootstrap, mas se você quer abrir o modal tanto pelo click no botão como por outro evento, é válido fazer isso, para não repetir código.

```js
$(function () {

      $('#open-modal').trigger('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button id="open-modal" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Simplificando o código, eu adicionei um `id` ao botão que abre o modal e usei um `trigger` para disparar o evento atrelado ao click do botão.